# AppsFlyer OneLink for iOS is referencing unwanted App Clip which can’t be removed

Tags: ios, apple-appclips, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

for our app we use AppsFlyers OneLink tool (e.g. for deeplinks). The hosted `{our-branded-domain.tld}/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` is referencing the expected `applinks`, but also an app clip which we do not want to have. A very old version of the app contained an app clip, but since several versions this app clip is gone and not part of the product anymore. Neither in the Xcode project nor in the App Store Connect portal I can find any reference to any app clip. In the developer account we had several profiles and identifiers for an app clip, which I removed completely. The App Site Association file from AppsFlyer is still referencing the appclips though.

Is there any other place I’m missing on how to completely remove App Clips from our app? Is there a way to force AppsFlyer to recreate the App Site Association file?

Thanks for your help!